# Define and call a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to define a function in my script file and it be accessible from all points in my document.

Comment: Uhm, just define a function and the reference the script in your master/layout/main page (like below the spot where you reference the jQuery library itself) and you can access it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function in your javascript file like this :

```
(function addModifiedRules(){
/* your code here */
})();
```

And load this javascript file when you load you jsp page or your content.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will define a global function that can be called anywhere in the document (the order of declaration and calling does not matter)

```
function myFunction(){
   console.log("You just called me!!! How could you!!!")
}
```

And then anywhere in the document

```
myFunction();
```

If you have this stored in another script file, you need to import it into your main document. In the  tags:

```
<script src='directory/scriptname.js'></script>
```

------------------ Extra information, as required ------------------

If you want a function to be defined on a jQuery selection, something like this is required. It is essentially code that first slides the content up and then removes it from the page:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    slideOut: function(){
        $(this).slideUp(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

This can be called using:

```
$("#divId").slideOut();
```

There are other ways you can define functions, such as prototyping, where you call functions to act on objects. Let's say you want to capitalise the first letter in a string:

```
String.prototype.capitalise = function(){
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

This can be called using:

```
"hello".capitalise() //returns Hello
```